# \verbatiminput stopped working?

Tags: xetex, verbatim

In the past, I've used the `\verbatiminput` command in `\fancyvrb` without problems, but today it's not working for me. I checked, and 
`/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fancyvrb/fancyvrb.sty` is still installed. Perhaps a system upgrade to some other part of Tex changed something?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{report}

\usepackage{fancyvrb}

\begin{document}

Here is the listing of |creatur-examples.cabal|.
\verbatiminput{creatur-examples.cabal}

\end{document}
```

Here is the output:

```
amy@wombat$ xelatex -shell-escape -interaction=nonstopmode AmyTest
This is XeTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-0.9999.3 (TeX Live 2013/Debian)
 \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./AmyTest.tex
LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>
Babel <3.9k> and hyphenation patterns for 2 languages loaded.
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/report.cls
Document Class: report 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fancyvrb/fancyvrb.sty
Style option: `fancyvrb' v2.7a, with DG/SPQR fixes, and firstline=lastline fix 
<2008/02/07> (tvz) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty
)) (./AmyTest.aux)
! Undefined control sequence.
l.8 \verbatiminput
                  {creatur-examples.cabal}
[1] (./AmyTest.aux) )
(see the transcript file for additional information)
Output written on AmyTest.pdf (1 page).
Transcript written on AmyTest.log.
```

And here's the log:

```
This is XeTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-0.9999.3 (TeX Live 2013/Debian) (format=xelatex 2014.4.15)  21 MAY 2014 17:13
entering extended mode
 \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**AmyTest
(./AmyTest.tex
LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>
Babel <3.9k> and hyphenation patterns for 2 languages loaded.
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/report.cls
Document Class: report 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo
File: size10.clo 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count80
\c@chapter=\count81
\c@section=\count82
\c@subsection=\count83
\c@subsubsection=\count84
\c@paragraph=\count85
\c@subparagraph=\count86
\c@figure=\count87
\c@table=\count88
\abovecaptionskip=\skip41
\belowcaptionskip=\skip42
\bibindent=\dimen102
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fancyvrb/fancyvrb.sty
Package: fancyvrb 2008/02/07

Style option: `fancyvrb' v2.7a, with DG/SPQR fixes, and firstline=lastline fix 
<2008/02/07> (tvz) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty
Package: keyval 1999/03/16 v1.13 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks14
)
\FV@CodeLineNo=\count89
\FV@InFile=\read1
\FV@TabBox=\box26
\c@FancyVerbLine=\count90
\FV@StepNumber=\count91
\FV@OutFile=\write3
) (./AmyTest.aux)
\openout1 = `AmyTest.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.

! Undefined control sequence.
l.8 \verbatiminput
                  {creatur-examples.cabal}
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

[1

] (./AmyTest.aux) ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 614 strings out of 495658
 8413 string characters out of 6187951
 54908 words of memory out of 5000000
 3887 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 3640 words of font info for 14 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 14 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 23i,4n,19p,134b,107s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s

Output written on AmyTest.pdf (1 page).
```

Comment: `\verbatiminput` is the command used with the `verbatim` package.  `fancyvrb` requires "camel case" as pointed out by david carlisle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
\VerbatimInput{creatur-examples.cabal}
```